# Активизация функции редактирования polygon.editor.startDrawing()

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Команда polygon.editor.startDrawing() редактирования  включает с собой режим добавления новых вершин в многоугольник, нужно отменить данный режим методом Canceled

прошу привести рабочий пример отмены добавление новых вершин в текущий  многоугольник при активации polygon.editor.startDrawing(), задача создать новый многоугольник в слое polygon

ссылка на документацию
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geometryEditor.Polygon-docpage/

Пример из песочницы
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/polygonEditor

Comment: В документации описано что есть stopDrawing и stopEditing https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geometryEditor.Polygon-docpage/#method_detail__stopDrawing Это не то что вам нужно?

Comment: Нет данный метод stopEditing завершает режим редактирования мне нужно добавить новый многоугольник , а не само редактирование

Comment: Ну тогда как-то так https://jsfiddle.net/vzos8kbu/

Comment: ага , спасибо как рабочий вариант... но данная автоматизация она не правильная

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду, что "данная автоматизация она не правильная" ?

Comment: Потому что каждый многоугольник, фигура фиксируется как новый слой.... А это не так ... скорее это много многоугольников в одном слое. Вот именно в этом и состоит ошибка

Comment: Вы решили свою задачу? Вы хотите чтобы все многоугольники были контурами одного многоугольника, но при этом рисование/редактирование было включено только на одном контуре этого многоугольника? Такое невозможно.